# Ads doesn't appear after removing and adding again

Tags: asp.net, ads, adsense

The ads not appear after I have removed and re-added the Adsense code.

I did not change and use the default code as

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:block"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-myid"
 data-ad-slot="id2"
 data-ad-format="auto"
 data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
 <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

How can I fix this ? Thanks

Comment: There's a google support page on this:
<https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/181960?hl=en> Alternatively, you could show the code you used, for possible bugs.

Comment: check if you are using ad blocker. The amount of info you have provided, that's the only thing we can say for now

Comment: @It's a trap No I'm not using ad blocker.

Comment: @DataDeer.net Thank you, I realised that my ID may be changed after I have removed the code, so I should add the new code. But its not seen on the link you have given.

Answer (score 4):

Go to adsense and make sure that your website is added "sites". If the site is not there than the ads will be disabled

I find when playing around with Adsense it takes some time for google to "accept/process" the changes.

Usually, in an hr and they will be up and running.

Also, try placing the script in the head section instead of the body and place the html into the body as needed.

i find you can add the entire chuck or you can separate it out(both have worked for me).

Comment: Also check out your ads. it maybe that it is not configured for your new layout

Comment: Yes my website is listed on the Sites tab.

Comment: Are you placing in a div that doesn't have any height sometimes the CSS will hide the overflow and it won't show

Comment: No I didn't place it in a div. It was inside UpdatePanel. I made it without UpdatePanel, but nochange.

Comment: Did you go to adsense and ensure that the ad is active? `adsense.com->ads->ad units->name of add`  If it is active click on the ad and make sure the settings are correct. Click save for any changes. Also you can use auto ads(which work well on mobile). The code is slightly different - try that

Comment: If you saved anything with respect to the ad - it may take some time to show(call it an hr)

Comment: Also make sure you are including this in the head of ur doc `<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>`

Comment: I did these but not work. (I didn't change the ad unit settings and have added the line to the head).

Comment: But could you tell me where I can get the Adsense code again. Maybe my ID have been changed after I have removed - and I want to compare the Adsense codes

Comment: Okey I found - its in Ad Units page.

Comment: My friend had been clicked to my ad, can Google be blocked my ads ? ...

Comment: Yes Google has control of the ads. Try a different browser some do a better job of using ad blocks

Comment: Sorry for my English - I mean "may Google blocked it". @Jujubes The problem exists on both Chrome, Yandex and IE. By thw way, there seems no error on Politicy page on my Adsense account.

Comment: Open up chrome console and see if there is any JavaScript errors blocking it

Comment: Google has complete control. If they think that you have violated their policy they can prevent the ad from being seen. You also could be region locked. Or your website could be blacklisted from Google. Tough to say

Comment: Try refreshing your browser and deleting your cookies for the site. Open up inspector hold down the refresh button and three options will.popup. click the bottom one to completely delete everything associatied to the site. Other than that I think there is an issue with ur acct which may be a Google thing directly

Comment: No I don't, I try on server

Comment: Did you try using a VPN to see if you are region locked?

Comment: you could also try putting the ad inside a div where you position it absolutely and use z-index to bring it to the top add some height and width. If the ad displays here that there is some css issues on your site. if it doesnt im really out of suggestions. If your site it the one i mentioned. it could be due to google not liking that type of site as of perceived copyright infringement - which you would need to clear up with them

Comment: My website does not have any music or video file, it only have title texts, so I don't think I have a copyright problem. Okey I'll try to check

Comment: I copied the ad code to a totally blank page and it gived this warning: "The resource https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190408/r20190131/show_ads_impl.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally."

Comment: Can you show the code you used to include the script ex:`<script scr="...."></script>`

Comment: It also may be easier if you set up a sandbox(jsfiddle) so i can look at the code. You may have an incomplete html element which is breaking the page

Comment: I have copied the code to a blank page, thank you - and now I found something;
if I add

&fbclid=IwAR16smh76DFOSOg6jLQurBz67-l2COSW7SjY2r5MiK8zZk9NMm6yo0BmGWA

to my adresses like
en.hqtunes.com/MusicDetail/?Music=Agartha_Crossing
then the ad become visible.

Comment: No problem. Now I do this : I have changed the ad unit, maybe the ads will appear from now on

Answer (score 0):

I heard that my website need to be re-accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I'm using `ad unit` code rather than using the code which is given on sign up.